# Google Analytics - visits to page vs views of page

Tags: google-analytics, metrics

I am a bit confused by Google's terminology. I understand the difference between *visitors*, *visits* and *pageviews* but I am confused about what a '*visit*' to a particular page means.

For example - I am looking at numbers for the past 12 months.

Two pages as an example:

- **Page #1**

  - 511 visits
  - 5813 unique pageviews
  - 7123 pageviews
- **Page #2**

  - 520 visits,
  - 5884 unique pageviews,
  - 7210 pageviews

The reason I am confused is because of the massive discrepancy in the figures. Can anyone help me understand how a visit to a web page differs to a unique pageview?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 metrics defined as visits in analytics:

- **Visits** - the number of people who accessed your website
- **Unique Visits** - the number of unique people who accessed your website

The difference between **unique pageviews** and **pageviews** is the same, **pageviews** being the total amount of times a page was accessed, where **unique pageviews** is the unique amount of page views for a specific page.

This means that if a single (unique) visitor opens a page once, it will add to both the **unique** and the **total pageviews**, if they open the same page again it will only add to the **pageviews**

Comment: That's not quite the question I am asking. I am wanting to know the difference between visits and pageviews as it relates to a page. In the examples I have there is a massive difference between the two - I'm not sure why

Comment: A visit is a person coming to your website. A pageview is that person viewing a page, which can be done multiple times per visit (ie; they can go to many pages on your site in a single visit)

Comment: So you're saying from the numbers above that visits who browse Page 1 have an average of 5813/511=11.37 unique pageviews / visit?

Comment: That's what it looks like. Try compare that to you average pageviews per visit stat and see if they match up

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply - I had to get the report writing down. eskimo and Tom - this is why I am confused. The site's average pageviews is 2.89 per visit which is significantly lower than 11.37